# R equivalent of scikit's KFold

Tags: r, cross-validation, scikit-learn, caret

I'm trying to set up a basic k folds CV loop in R.
In Python I'd use scikit's `KFold`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
Y = np.array([1, 1, 3, 4])

kf = KFold(len(Y), n_folds=2, indices=False)

for train, test in kf:
      print("%s %s" % (train, test))
[False False  True  True] [ True  True False False]
[ True  True False False] [False False  True  True]
```

In R I was trying to use createFolds from the caret package, but it seems as though it's trying to do a stratified sample on the response variable.

```
library(caret)

Y <- c(1, 1, 3, 4)

fold <- createFolds(Y, 2)

fold
$Fold1
[1] 2 3

$Fold2
[1] 1 4
```

All I need is a simple k folds split. How do you do that in R?

Answer (score 2):

Load `caret` and read `?createFolds`. By default, the function returns which data are held out in each fold (there is an example from eariler today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909197/creating-folds-for-k-fold-cv-in-r-using-caret/22914053#22914053)).

If you want the same thing, just convert the indicies to logicals:

```
> library(caret)
> library(mlbench)
> data(Sonar)
> 
> set.seed(1)
> dat <- sample(Sonar$Class, 5)
> 
> folds <- createFolds(dat, 2)
> folds
$Fold1
[1] 2 4

$Fold2
[1] 1 3 5

> is_train <- lapply(folds, function(ind, n) !(1:n %in% ind),
+                    n = length(dat))
> is_train
$Fold1
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

$Fold2
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Max

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the OP question? Isn't this still using stratification on the response variable? Instead, I guess OP is looking for a strategy that doesn't use stratification at all?